# AS3 - Find JSON node by content

Tags: json, string, actionscript-3

I need to find out in which `id` the value *stackoverflow* is in. How to do that?

```
{
 "kind": "blogList",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "blog",
   "id": "stackoverflow",
   "selfLink": "https://example.com",
   "posts": {
    "totalItems": 0,
    "selfLink": "https://www.foo.bar"
   },
   "pages": {
    "totalItems": 0,
    "selfLink": "https://www.example.com"
   },
   "locale": {
    "language": "en",
    "country": "",
    "variant": ""
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "google",
   "selfLink": "https://www.foo.bar",
   "posts": {
    "totalItems": 0,
    "selfLink": "https://www.test.com"
   },
   "pages": {
    "totalItems": 0,
    "selfLink": "https://www.example.com"
   },
   "locale": {
    "language": "en",
    "country": "",
    "variant": ""
   }
  },
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON into an object? Loop over `items` and check each one.

Comment: Please see this links:

[LINK1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6967515/1563878)


[LINK1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1653628/1563878)

Comment: Download as3corelib.swc from here http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/downloads/list?can=1&q= Import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON; and use it like this var newJsonObj:Object = JSON.decode( new MyJson() ) where MyJson is a class of the above json embeded as a file in your project

Comment: Embed like this  [Embed(source = "/../assets/MyJson.json", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
  public static const MyJson:Class;

Comment: if jsonObject:Object = {...above code here...} than your required property can be get like this jsonObject["items"][0]["id"] = "stackoverflow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code, this will be useful as an example (its works perfectly) (download this [library](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json) before):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.utils.ArrayUtil;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import lib.JSON;
            private var jsonString:String = '{"root":[{"id":"val1"},{"id":"val2"}]}';

            public function init():void{
                var decodedObj:Object = JSON.decode(jsonString);
                Alert.show(decodedObj["root"][0].id); //prints val1
                Alert.show(ArrayUtil.toArray(decodedObj["root"])[1].id); //prints val2
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```